# Access an authenticated gae application from Google Apps Script

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps-script

I need to access a Google App Engine application that requires the user to be logged on my Google domain from a Google Apps Script script, but cannot find any information on how to do it...

The GAE application has a URL that returns a json (I can test it when I'm logged in my Google account), but when I access this URL through my GAS script (with UrlFetchApp.fetch) the return I get is an HTML page (probably the Google login page).

Is there any way to tell the GAS script to use my credential to access this URL?

Comment: You need to send an authorization header. Review OAuth tokens

Comment: I believe that sending OAuth tokens may be the way to go, and I have found this library (https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2) for GAS, but I couldn't understand how to use it... I wanted the GAS script to use the credentials of the user executing the script, and not to hard code credentials in the code. Is it possible? Can someone point me to any examples of that?

Comment: Using native methods for other Google APIs is probably easier. If you have the proper scopes in the web app, you can pass https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#getoauthtoken . If you need to use custom scopes and such, then adding the OAuth library you linked may be necessary.